# HTTP large file transfer

Tags: browser, file-upload

It is necessary to transmit large file using web browser interface. Standard `<input type=”file”>` or `<asp:FileUpload>` do not provide enough feedback for the user of the application. What are the realistic ways to improve feedback such as progress bar, animation, etc? Target users are users with IE, Firefox and Safari browsers. All I know that animated GIFs are not working during file post, users are not looking at the progress line in the status bar or other small icons, and word AJAX is not that helpful in the solution of this problem :-)

EDITED: users do not want to install any ActiveXs  or applets. Users are fine with `<input type=”file”>` but they want feedback – users keep referring youtube. How youtube did it? Is it a secret? The server part can be modified to have a custom handler. Did HTML authors and web browsers implementers make file upload control that completely useless?

Answer (score 3):

We use a product for our .NET application, called SlickUpload: http://krystalware.com/Products/SlickUpload/

It provides upload progress indicators and information.

Comment: Nice, that should be provided as a part of the standard library

Comment: Is there any reason why it handles only file with size up to 4 GB?

Comment: Not sure why it only handles up to 4GB.  Their support has been reasonably good at answering questions, so I wouldn't hesitate to ask them to see if there is a work around or something they can do to support greater than that.

Comment: Used it for years and love it.  Chris, the guy who built it, really knows his stuff.

Comment: 4GB is the max enforced by IIS. Most browsers don't support > 4GB uploads either. I'm the author of SlickUpload, btw - SlickUpload doesn't limit the size of uploads. We're working on a Silverlight shim that will chunk uploads to handle basically unlimited file sizes. That should be available soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to return status information about the file upload, you need to somehow interface your app to the webserver receiving the upload.
Some servers will let you define an upload handler. Here is [an example I found](http://www.devstack.com/articles/apache2-asp-file-uploads/) that uses Apache + ASP.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using silverlight and can build/host a WCF service or an HttpHandler you can check this one out. [Silverlight Multi File Uploader](http://www.codeplex.com/SLFileUpload) will provide progress bar information and multi file upload.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use flash for this, you could take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FlashUpload.aspx

There are sources and explanations for the project, so it could be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Java, I recommend [jUpload](http://jupload.sourceforge.net/), it can be customized quite well and will split large files to prevent your server from choking.

Answer (score -1):

Chilkat controls have one that does this http://www.chilkatsoft.com/HttpActiveX.asp

They have ones for ASP, Ruby,Python etc.